# IE6 Script Tag error

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-6

I've never seen this error. We have some clients that use Internet Explorer 6, so we need some pages to work on it.

We have the following HTML code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var bust = 236;
</script>
```

IE6 is throwing the following error message: `'Undefined' is null or not an object`.

Do you have any idea what it might be?
Thanks.

Comment: Isn't there in the HTML the element with `id="bust"`? Ancient IEs used to make global variables from the IDs and this sometimes led to surprises.

Comment: IE6? Seriously? No one, not even Microsoft, supprts that

Comment: *"I'm sorry but there is no other option but for you to stop using IE6"* is an all-round win.

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn: Not just ancient IEs, all browsers do it, and so much code relies on it that it's [been standardized](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#named-access-on-the-window-object).

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn so if I use a variable named `button` it will probably throw an error?

Comment: Please update your question with [mcve] demonstrating the problem (surely just what you currently have doesn't). In case someone can still dig up a virtual machine with IE6 in it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder done

Comment: @MaurícioGiordano: **Code**, not a *picture* of code. :-) Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like `bust` is conflicting with some other global. The global name space is *really* crowded.

You may be able to resolve it by wrapping your code in a scoping function so that it's not at global scope anymore:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
    var bust = 236;
})();
</script>
```

Or if it **has** to be a global, try another name until you find one that doesn't cause the problem. Global variables aren't fundamentally broken, even in IE6.

Comment: Actually I need this variable to be global. It is used in all of our javascript files.

Comment: @MaurícioGiordano: Probably, if there isn't also a `_bust` global it's conflicting with.

Comment: Yep. Global variables. The implementation of them may not be broken (not even in IE6), but excessive use of them in any context (or indeed in any language) is always a sign of bad code, and has a habit of coming back to bite you.

Comment: @Simba: Yup. :-) I limit myself to one with a target of zero. (Said target will be a lot easier to achieve soon, as module support appears. :-) )